# Delphi Android Oreo: How to start service in foreground?

Tags: android, delphi

I need to start a service for Android Oreo in foreground but I can't find an example how to do this in Delphi 10.3 for the app and for the service.

I found hints that I have to use startForegroundService in the app and startForeground in the service but I do not know how and where to use these calls.

In the app I start my service with

```pascal
  FService := TLocalServiceConnection.Create;
  FService.StartService('MySvc');
```

In the service I execute the following statement:

```pascal
function TDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject; const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of how to start and stop a service in the foreground:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.Support, Androidapi.Helpers;

procedure TServiceModule.StartForeground;
var
  LBuilder: JNotificationCompat_Builder;
begin
  LBuilder := TJNotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(TAndroidHelper.Context);
  LBuilder.setAutoCancel(True);
  LBuilder.setContentTitle(StrToJCharSequence('Title'));
  LBuilder.setContentText(StrToJCharSequence('Text'));
  LBuilder.setSmallIcon(TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationInfo.icon);
  LBuilder.setTicker(StrToJCharSequence('Caption'));
  // 1413 is just a number picked at random
  TJService.Wrap(System.JavaContext).startForeground(1413, LBuilder.build);
end;

procedure TServiceModule.StopForeground;
begin
  TJService.Wrap(System.JavaContext).stopForeground(True);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Dave. Where do I have to call StartForeground? I tried various places in my service but the service and my app always hang not a second after calling StartForeground. And how can I start my app in foreground? Do you have an example for this, please?

Comment: A more complete demo can be found here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/tree/master/Demos/AndroidLocation. The main thing is that the app and service can send "messages" to each other, and the app notifies the service when the app is going into the background so the service knows to call startForeground, and conversely call stopForeground when the app becomes active

Comment: Thank you, Dave. I will have a closer look at the demo in the next days.